# Other methods to use table variables than dynamic query

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure to count number of records.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE spCountAnyTableRows
    (@PassedTableName as NVarchar(255)) 
AS
    -- Counts the number of rows from any non-system Table, *SAFELY*
BEGIN
    DECLARE @ActualTableName AS NVarchar(255)

    SELECT @ActualTableName = QUOTENAME( TABLE_NAME )
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
    WHERE TABLE_NAME = @PassedTableName

    DECLARE @sql AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
    SELECT @sql = 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ' + @ActualTableName + ';'

    EXEC(@SQL)
END
```

Now, I want to use more complex queries to replace the simple query in `@sql` defined above, and I have to use table alias in my query since there are many joins. I do not how to do use table alias in dynamic queries.

My question: if there is a way to use table alias, any other ways to use table variables in stored procedure?

Comment: Before you go too far... If this for anything facing the web, stop and learn about SQL injection & how to properly parameter your dynamic sql. The way you have that written, you're a bit of a sitting duck.

Comment: No, internal use only. Let's assume 0 security requirements for simplicity.

Comment: Yea... It's should be easy enough to code. The question is how do you plan on actually using it? Are you setting up some sort of interface that will allow you to use a pick-list or are forcing yourself to memorize the reliant parts of the schema? In either case, forget the INFORMATION_SCHEMA views... You want the sys.scema views that expose the ids that make it easy to get from database, to schema, to tables to columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whats the big deal in having alias names in dynamic sql, assign each table name variable with alias name.

```
SELECT @ActualTableName = QUOTENAME( TABLE_NAME ) + ' as a'
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
WHERE TABLE_NAME = @PassedTableName
```

Make sure you provide unique alias names to the tables involved in same query.

or even inside dynamic query you can provide alias names

```
SELECT @sql = 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ' + @ActualTableName + ' as a ;'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
/* This Script is use to Fetch To count the Numbers of rows in Table */
CREATE TABLE  #rowcount (tablename VARCHAR(128), cnt INT)
EXEC sp_MSforeachtable
 @command1 = 'Insert into #rowcount select ''?'',
              count(*) from ?',
 @whereand = 'and o.name = ''Table_Name''',   -- Table_Name
 @postcommand = 'SELECT * from #rowcount Where Cnt >0  Order by tablename'

DROP TABLE  #rowcount

OR YOU Can Get All Table Row Count by removing Where clause

CREATE TABLE  #rowcount (tablename VARCHAR(128), cnt INT)
EXEC sp_MSforeachtable
 @command1 = 'Insert into #rowcount select ''?'',
              count(*) from ?',
 @postcommand = 'SELECT * from #rowcount Where Cnt >0  Order by tablename'

DROP TABLE  #rowcount
```